# What is the meaning of session states in SQL Server, such as sleeping, suspended, running etc

Tags: sql-server

I'm confused about the session states of SQL Server sessions. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx):

- dormant = SQL Server is resetting the session.
- running = The session is running one or more batches. When Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is enabled, a session can run multiple batches. For more information, see Using Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS).
- background = The session is running a background task, such as deadlock detection.
- rollback = The session has a transaction rollback in process.
- pending = The session is waiting for a worker thread to become available.
- runnable = The task in the session is in the runnable queue of a scheduler while waiting to get a time quantum.
- spinloop = The task in the session is waiting for a spinlock to become free.
- suspended = The session is waiting for an event, such as I/O, to complete.

Comment: Also can refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453 if you are interested in a more detailed explanation about understanding blocking if that is indeed what you are trying to understand through these states..

Comment: I didn't understand dormant state. What does "resetting the session" means. What really happens when resetting a session and why?

Answer (score -3):

If you refere to ASP.NET Session State using SQL Server then a session string is stored in a table in SQL Server. This is makes it possible to use the same session across multiple webservers. Otherwise when using ASP.NET InProc (In Process) session state, the system is storeing the session in a process on a singel maschine and can therefor not be used in a webfarm.

Comment: -1 Question was not related to ASP.NET Session State mechanism.